# HDFS Secondary name node availability

Tags: hdfs

In HDFS, when the primary name node is down does the secondary node exactly act as the primary name node? Does the SNN has the block location details? if not, then please explain the purpose of SNN. 
When the data node is down and the client tries to access the files will the data be retrieved? (since SNN is up)

Answer (score 1):

From their [FAQ](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/FAQ#What_is_the_purpose_of_the_secondary_name-node.3F):

> The term "secondary name-node" is somewhat misleading. It is not a name-node in the sense that data-nodes cannot connect to the secondary name-node, and in no event it can replace the primary name-node in case of its failure.
>
> The only purpose of the secondary name-node is to perform periodic checkpoints. The secondary name-node periodically downloads current name-node image and edits log files, joins them into new image and uploads the new image back to the (primary and the only) name-node.

So if the name-node fails and you can restart it on the same physical node then there is no need to shutdown data-nodes, just the name-node need to be restarted. If you cannot use the old node anymore you will need to copy the latest image somewhere else. The latest image can be found either on the node that used to be the primary before failure if available; or on the secondary name-node. The latter will be the latest checkpoint without subsequent edits logs, that is the most recent name space modifications may be missing there. You will also need to restart the whole cluster in this case.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Does the SNN also store the block details like the name node which stores it in-memory?

Comment: This is a new question and it has it's own response which is a long one, but short answer would be yes, SNN loads both snapshots and EditLogs into memory and stores the latest checkpoint in a directory which is structured the same way as the primary NameNode's directory.